# Firefox 15: div content spilling to border-image

Tags: html, css, firefox

First off, I'm aware of the unprefixing of -moz-border-image in Firefox 15, as described here:
http://dbaron.org/log/20120612-border-image. 
I fixed my CSS to work with Firefox 15 in that respect. My problem is different (although probably tangential).

In short, in Firefox 15 the content of a div with border-image now overlaps said border-image, as if the border was part of the div's interior.
Other browsers don't display the issue and behave as expected, which prevents me from simply compensating for the border with padding (other browsers would then have excessive padding).

How do I solve this? Thanks!

See [example](http://games4e.com/tests/borderimage.php) page

My code:

```
<style type="text/css">

    body { background: yellow; }

    .borderbox {
    -moz-border-image: url(border_sprite.png) 31 25 25 20 / 31px 25px 25px 20px repeat stretch;
    -webkit-border-image: url(border_sprite.png) 31 25 25 20 fill repeat stretch;
    -o-border-image: url(border_sprite.png) 31 25 25 20 repeat stretch;
    border-image: url(border_sprite.png) 31 25 25 20 fill repeat stretch;
    border-width: 31px 25px 25px 20px;
    border-image-width: 31px 25px 25px 20px;
    padding: 0 10px 20px 0;
    text-align: right;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    color: purple;
    font-size: 20px;
 }

</style>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head></head>
<body>

<div class="borderbox">
    the content should be bound to the inner white box. Why does it also cover the blue border in Firefox 15?
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer - so simple (yet seemingly arbitrary). Add the following property to the div's style:

```
border-style: solid;
```

Comment: It's not arbitrary.  It's just that `border-image` used to force `border-style: solid` in Gecko but per spec it doesn't do that anymore.